# JSON basic format for manufacturer/product array for jQuery import

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, text

I have a list of a few manufacturers, each of whom provide a small array of product types. Can't find an exact example of formatting this as a JSON file.

manufacturelist
...manufacturer#1
.....pumps
.....valves
.....gauges
...manufacturer#2
.....valves
.....tubing
...manufacturer#2
.....insulation
.....tubing

So each manufacturer has a small array of product type. I will have use jQuery to search this list for a specific manufacturer# and display the type of products that manufacturer sells. I was told to use JSON as the simplest route that can be easily edited. The JSON file will be in the /json directory on the root of the server.

Comment: To learn about JSON: http://json.org/.

Answer (score 0):

```
{"manufacturelist":[
    {"manufacturer#1": ['pumps', 'valves', 'gauges']},
    {"manufacturer#2": ['valves', 'tubing']},
    {"manufacturer#3": ['insulation', 'tubing']}
]}
```

I believe that this will achieve what you want.  I'd take the # out of those keys if you can since you can't access via dot notation otherwise (i.e. `obj.manufacturelist.manufacturer#1` is invalid).

Comment: that would cause an error if you don't put all the manufacturer objets into an array:
`{"manufacturelist":[
    {"manufacturer#1": ['pumps', 'valves', 'gauges']},
    {"manufacturer#2": ['valves', 'tubing']},
    {"manufacturer#3": ['insulation', 'tubing']}]
}`

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the #'s, just an off-hand example. I'll try the format as described, I do know how to get it into jQuery. Yes I did read the json docs but my brain works backwards I'm afraid and I just really needed help for once. I'll post the results here later.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is really easy and you should structure it according to the easiest way to read it (at least I think that way)

For your specific problem, I would do something like this:

```
{
    "manufacturerList":[
        {"id":1, "productTypes":["pumps","valves","gauges"]}, //I added here a prop id but you could add any other you need
        {"id":2, "productTypes":["valves","tubing"]},
        {"id":3, "productTypes":["insulation","tubing"]}
    ]
}
```

Hope that helps